# How to refresh CGridView control using values from other controls

Tags: javascript, web-applications, yii

I have set up a CGridView widget in my application. It displays a list of user accounts. I also have two other drop down lists that basically filter out the users. My problem is that I cannot use the values from the drop down lists to filter out the users. What I actually need is to refresh the list of user accounts based on the selected values from the drop down lists.

How am I supposed to do that with Javascript?

Comment: using selection `Onchange` event and register a callback.

Comment: Yes, I already have a callback event for the onchange event (using jQuery). What I actually need is to pass the values of the list boxes to the url that the CGridView control calls to fetch the list of accounts and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you use Javascript to do this. CGridView's [jquery.yiigridview.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js#L222) has `$('#id-of-grid').yiiGridView('update', options)` function which can be used for such things:

```
function(){// in your function
    $('#id-of-grid').yiiGridView('update', {data: {value_of_list: $(this).val()}});
}
```

This will call the url that renders this view with a parameter `value_of_list` with the value selected in the drop down.

**Edit:**

The `$('#id-of-grid').yiiGridView('update', options)` signature indicates that you can specify which grid to update, and also the specific options to be sent. In the above example i have sent only `data`, i could have also specified which url to send the data to using `url` option. The full list of options can be seen in the link i have specified above.

Comment: Offering people to use deprecated methods? Way to go. `$('#id-of-grid').yiiGridView('update', options)`

Comment: ah, i'm still using 1.1.8, which resulted in this mistake, updated, thanx.

Comment: OK, I have another issue now. It seems that the value passed from the second drop down list is remembered for the next calls. The second drop down is dependant on the first one (the latter is hidden when a specific value from the first drop down is selected and its values are set to a non value). In this case, the value from the second drop down (although hidden) is passed again (I can see the GET values from the request). Is there a way to remove the value from the second drop down list from the GET array of the ajax call when the second drop down list is hidden?

Comment: @VasileiosLourdas How do you hide your second dropdown? In that javascript function simply remove all options from second dropdown. Something like `$('#second_dropdown').children().remove().end().hide();`

Comment: johnatan could be right, however i think its time we see your entire view file code to give you a better answer, there are quite a few things happening in your code, so i wouldn't want to risk a guess. I also don't know how you are making the call, so the actual issue could be anything. Therefore(imho) this deserves to be another question, preferably with the jquery, javascript tags added, in addition to yii to increase visibility to the best answerers there. Edit: anyway, i think there could be a mistake with the way you added the ajax call, so again its important to see the code now.

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue with a hack, I passed the value of the second drop down list with to the ajax call with the 0 value. It works (for now).

Comment: My point is that CGridView is not maybe for all cases. Yes, it's somewhat flexible, but not too much. For example, I want to dynamically hide/show columns depending on the drop down lists values and there does not seem to exist an easy and quick way to do this. Maybe, I should code the grid myself and load its contents with ajax calls. The sorting would be an issue, but it's not a feature I couldn't live without. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: it's great that you solved it! however if you share the code, we could **possibly unearth the real issue** here. it could end up being helpful for future visitors, so don't hesitate to ask a new question, if you have the time. I agree that the gridview is not very flexible, that's why it is so easy to `extend` it, and write up your own gridview class. again i'm glad that i could help out.